# Copying and Share multiple texts of ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui

I want to thank everyone who helps me out with my SwiftUI learning journey. Here, I have some questions related to SwiftUI. According to iOS 15, I believe that we can copy or share texts easily by using .textSelection(.enabled) modifier. What if I want to copy or share texts from a ForEach loop by using a button. As far as my research goes, it is possible to copy or share a single-line text. For example, as you can see in my codes below, I want to copy the cities, name1, and name2 all at once by tapping on the 'COPY Button'. I am not sure it is possible to it in SwiftUi. If it is not, is there an alternative approach to copy text using SwiftUI. Thanks again to everyone who help me out.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MobileCoreServices

struct DataArray: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let cities: String
    let name1: String
    let name2: String

}

public struct ListDataArray {
    static let dot = [
    
    DataArray(id: 1,
        cities: "Baltimore"
        name1: "John",
        name2: "Mike"),
        
    DataArray(id: 2,
        cities: "Frederick"),
        name1: "Joe",
        name2: "Swift"),
        
    DataArray(id: 3,
        cities: "Catonsville"
        name1: "Susan",
        name2: "Oliver"),
        
    // There will be a lot of data     
    ]
}

class Prospect: ObservableObject {

    @Published var datas: [DataArray] = []
    
    init() {
        fetchDataArrays()
    }
    
    private func fetchDataArrays() {
        let items = ListDataArray.dot
        datas = items
    }
}

struct Home: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var items: Prospect
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
        
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(items.datas) { data in
                    
                    VStack {
                        ButtonView(data: data)
                            .padding(.vertical)
                        
                        Text("\(data.id)")
                            .font(.title3)
                        Text(data.cities)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        Text(data.name1)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        Text(data.name2)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ButtonView: View {
    
    let data: DataArray
    
    //var index: Int {
    //  items.datas.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == data.id }) ?? 0
    //}
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
        
            // Copy Button
            Button(action: {
                // I want to copy the whote texts not just cities or name1 or name2
                
            } label: {
                    
                Text("COPY")
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                // I want to share the whote texts not just cities or name1 or name2
            } label: {
                
                Text("SHARE")
            })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (tested with Xcode 13.1 and iOS 14+):

```swift
    // Copy Button
    Button(action: {
        let dataText = "\(data.city) - \(data.name1) - \(data.name2)"
        UIPasteboard.general.string = dataText
    } label: {
        Text("COPY")
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Henrique Mattos. It took me 2 weeks to get the answer until you showed me how to do it.